# table view show a new specifik table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

so i have this app that is a training program in this app the first screen is a tableview that has to contain some programs then when the user clicks on the table it loads the programs again in a tableview and show what exercises there is in this program

but i can't find a why to make the program decide what program  the user selected and then repressed the right exercises table

i alsov need a why to save all this data to a file ore if there is a better why to save the data pleas tell me.

alsov the add button is not completely don atm it just starts a new view where the user can enter name a off the program and when the user is inside the program it alsov can enter times but there i have the problem that i need to get the data from the add screen to the table view so i can create the cell

sry for my english 
pleas rember that im a noob programmer when you answere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   {

}
```

this method will tell the code which row is selected by user

Comment: yes i know that but who can i taie the first selection to the othere table ?? and nsindexpath who can i print it??

Comment: Do you mean indexPath.section and indexPath.row?

Comment: ya sry for the long replay time :-(

who will you recommend that i'm sloving the problem with a difrint traning program to load when difrint row is selected in the first table view??